# Redirect command as well as output to text file in Windows CLI?

Tags: windows, command-line, io-redirection

I need to redirect both the command as well as its output to a text file in Windows CLI. For instance, I am running the `nslookup` command on a subnet using a `FOR` loop,

```
for /L %i IN (1,1,254) DO nslookup 192.168.1.%i >> nslookup.txt
```

However, this only redirects the output of the command.

Is there a way to redirect both the command as well as the output to a text file? Please do not tell me about clip and select all/copy commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed the command with "cmd /c" to start a new command prompt, and redirect the output of the command prompt:

```
cmd /c for /L %i IN (1,1,254) DO nslookup 192.168.1.%i > nslookup.txt
```

Note that you only need to use a single greater than (>) since the output of cmd is going to nslookup.txt. Sadly, this misses the error output, so you are not seeing the ***Request to UnKnown timed-out for each failed address.

Comment: Simple and elegant! This is exactly what I wanted, as I am not really concerned about the error output. Thank you! Care to explain why single greater than (>) doesn't overwrite the file?

Comment: The single greater than **does** overwrite the file. But the overwrite is only done once (for the cmd), so will contain the output of all the nslookup commands. If you need to save the file because it has output from previous invocations, then you will need to use two greater than (>>).

Answer (score 0):

Your `FOR` loop is right on and it sounds like you are already getting the output you want, so all you need to do is `ECHO` the command before running it:

```
for /L %i IN (1,1,254) DO ECHO nslookup 192.168.1.%i&nslookup 192.168.1.%i >> nslookup.txt
```

The `&` chains the commands together so the `ECHO` is run before the `nslookup`.

If you want to use a batch file, it becomes a bit more clear:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET Outfile=nslookup.txt

REM Log the date/time.
ECHO %DATE% - %TIME%>%Outfile%

FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,254) DO (
    SET Command=nslookup 192.168.1.%%i

    REM Print the command being run.
    ECHO !Command!>>%Outfile%

    REM Run the command.
    !Command!>>%Outfile%
)

ENDLOCAL
```

Answer (score 0):

for /L %i IN (1,1,254) DO (@echo nslookup 192.168.1.%i & nslookup 192.168.1.%i) >> nslookup.txt

This works. Still I'm sure there are smarter ways to do this.